# how client sending client's public key to server?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

as of my research on google, i got that rsa works on this way.

1. A client (for example browser) sends its public key to the server and requests for some data.
2. The server encrypts the data using client’s public key and sends the encrypted data.
3. Client receives this data and decrypts it

my question is, since we are communicating over https, everything should be encrypted. but how browser sending client's public key?

is it encrypted? cause server never shared servers public key to client (in order to encrypt public key of client)

how the 1st step happeningn-> (1. A client (for example browser) sends its public key to the server and requests for some data.)

thank you in advance.

Comment: This pretty far off from what actually happens in HTTPS. This is a tutorial level question and such questions are best left to any one of the numerous off-site tutorials available on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the public keys are public, we don't need to encrypt it. it is okay to send public key in plain text. even a third party get your public key, they cannot decrypt the data which is encrypted with public key by the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As @Nibras Muhammed said the properties of asymmetric encryption is such that the information encrypted using the public key can only be decrypted by the private key which should never be exposed by the client in this case. This mechanism can also work vice-versa, meaning the information encrypted using private key can only be decrypted using a public key.

Of course, it's also important to understand that asymmetric encryption is mostly used for the client and the server to exchange the shared symmetric key, which is used to facilitate much more efficient and faster form of encryption.